# Как отправлять сообщения из Low Level hook'а в главный поток

Tags: c++, winapi

Имеется код:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK LowLevelMouseProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    if (nCode == HC_ACTION) {
        switch (wParam) {
            case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
                SendMessage(NULL, PRIVATE_MSG, PM_MOUSEDOWN, 0);
                printf("Pressed\n");
                break;
            case WM_LBUTTONUP:
                SendMessage(NULL, PRIVATE_MSG, PM_MOUSEUP, 0);
                printf("Released\n");
                break;
        }
        CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }
}
```

Так же функция **main()**, которая обрабатывает сообщения:

```
    int main(int args, char** argv) {
    bool macroEnabled = 0;
    int xspeed = 1;
    int yspeed = 0;

    POINT mpoint;

    HHOOK hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, LowLevelMouseProc, 0, 0);

    MSG msg;
    while (!GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
        printf("Message received\n");
        if (msg.message == PRIVATE_MSG) {
            printf("Private message received\n");
            switch (msg.wParam) {
                case PM_MOUSEDOWN:
                    macroEnabled = 1;
                    break;
                case PM_MOUSEUP:
                    macroEnabled = 0;
                    break;
            }
        }
        if (macroEnabled) {
            GetCursorPos(&mpoint);
            SetCursorPos(mpoint.x + xspeed, mpoint.y + yspeed);
        }
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}
```

Но сообщения из хука не приходят.
Спасибо за внимание.

Comment: Попробуйте использовать `PostThreadMessage` вместо `SendMessage`.

Comment: Для него нужен id главного потока, который я могу получить только из главного потока.

Comment: Всё правильно, передавайте этот id из самого́ главного потока через глобальную переменную перед назначением хука.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сообщения не приходят, потому что первым параметром стоит NULL:

```
SendMessage(NULL, PRIVATE_MSG, PM_MOUSEDOWN, 0);
```

Должен стоять дескриптор окна-получателя сообщения - HWND.

Следует создать окно, но не показывать его. И направлять сообщения в него:

```
SendMessage(hWnd, PRIVATE_MSG, PM_MOUSEDOWN, 0);
```

Но если сообщение пересылается между потоками, то лучше использовать `PostMessage`. Оно не приводит к блокировке потока через мьютекс.